# mod_rewrite for 1 defined and other arbitrary parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling with mod_rewrite. Currently I have this url:

`http://localhost/products.php?page=3&sort=r90&range=25-50`

The page, sort and range parameters are not mandatory. What I like to have is the following working urls:

For page 1:

`http://localhost/products` --> `http://localhost/products.php`

For page 3:

`http://localhost/products/3/` --> `http://localhost/products.php?page=3`

For page 5 with n parameters:

`http://localhost/products/5/?sort=r90&range=25-50` --> `http://localhost/products.php?page=5&sort=r90&range=25-50`

I currently have this rule:

`^products/([0-9]+)$ http://localhost/products.php?page=$1`

which correctly works for:

`http://localhost/products/3/` and `http://localhost/products/`

However when I add parameters e.g. `http://localhost/products/2/?sort=r90&range=25-50`

It redirects to `http://localhost/products.php?sort=r90&range=25-50` (without the page parameter)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QSA flag. modify your current rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ /products.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

From [Apache's docs on mod-rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> ### Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string
>   to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old
>   query strings, use the `[QSA]` flag.

Comment: SQA did the trick. The manual about QSA: When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.